# Pythonic way of duplicating specific properties of a dict?

Tags: python, memory, dictionary, copy

Many times I find myself using `copy.deepcopy()` to create a duplicate of a `dict`, and then `del` properties that I don't require.

**I don't do the following:**

1. Refer to the existing `dict`; because I need to manipulate the values while retaining the original `dict`.
2. Copy specific properties of a `dict` that I really require; because sometimes I have to manipulate existing properties to create new ones (for new `dict`), after which I don't require the existing ones (in new `dict`).

**Alternatives I can think of:**

1. Generously use temporary variables instead of `copy.deepcopy` the entire `dict`, and let the temporary variables automatically expire with scope.

So, am I doing it the Pythonic way?

Comment: What do you mean by creating new ones with existing properties and then deleting them? I didn't understand point 2.

Comment: I meant that I need certain properties in the new `dict` that are not present in the old `dict`, but can be generated by modifying some existing properties of the old `dict`.

Comment: So why don't you copy these properties out of old dict first, then modify these properties in the new dict? As you said, you have to modify these in the old dict to create new dict anyway. In this way, you can use method of copying specific properties.

Comment: Yeah, I could, but that would leave me with the same problem i.e. I'll have to `del` the old properties from the new `dict` (once I've populated new properties with the modified forms of old ones).

Comment: Since key of dict could not be modified, you can only modify the value. right? If you modify the value, old properties have been changed, you don't need to del them. 'properties' in your word means key-value, right?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Mostly, though they might be nested dict/array themselves, but the problem is that I have to write the new `dict` somewhere, which demands that I delete the properties that I don't want to write.

Comment: I think you'd better post some examples and expected output in your question to help us understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `"foo"` and `"bar"` keys from the dict `a`, with their values deepcopy'ed, how about:

```
dict((x,copy.deepcopy(a[x])) for x in ('foo','bar'))
```

If you don't need copies of the values:

```
dict((x,a[x]) for x in ('foo','bar'))
```

Comment: As I said in the question too, in cases where I have to manipulate/modify some existing properties to create new ones, this won't work!